# Get all the supported extension list from windows

Tags: c#, python, .net, windows, powershell

I have a requirement where I need to get all the supported extension from windows OS. Now there are different windows versions available with differently known extensions (depending on the application they have installed), I need one script/Code using which I can fetch all the known extensions from OS.

Comment: what is the reason for negative ranking in this question??

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free programming service. That's why people have voted you down. You are supposed to post some code, that's giving you problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You're likely being down-voted because you have not show any of your own own code which reflects as making no effort. Asking others to do your work for you is not the spirit of this site and people don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any specific API, however in the end this data is stored in the Registery. For this area I would point you towarsd this MSDN article, wich has more information on that mater:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl

There are a few things to consider, however:

Due to programms doing what I can only describe as "Extension Wars", wich programm is associated with wich extension is now left to the user to choose. So write access will be tricky.

Another downside is, there can no longer be a simple 1:1 relationship. Every programm that **could** handle this extension will register with Windows. Wich one of those options to actually use is now up to the user. I have unfortunately no idea how that changes the underlying data structure in the registery. Or where those other options are stored.

Comment: Don't forget that by definition an extension doesn't have to be handled by anything. An example would be generic dat or bin files. Those might only be readable and writable by the application which created it. The original question could be answered as "Windows supports file extensions".

Comment: This is helpful Christopher :). I just need to know known extension by the OS, the mapping is not my concern.. Thanks

Comment: @KushagraMisra: Do you actually need the extension, or only need Windows to do the standart handling for a specific file (like opening it in the default browser)? Because the later part is way easier. The moment you punch a absolute path in the Run Dialog (or the Process.Run() Function), Windows will decide how to process that according to it's settings - either using the Extension or Protocoll to decide the handler, then picking the default action on that file.

Comment: @KushagraMisra you will have to spin up a VM of each OS you're interested in and dump that list. That way you will also account for patches etc.

Comment: @Seth: I think his goal is to retreive those values at runtime do to something with them. Just what that "something" is, is not clear. And as usual in such a case, it might be a XY problem.